How and where to specify weight field for class instance in ML.net?
I have a class named SkuInfo that represents products. I solving classification task and new to ML.net. Learn dataset is very imbalanced. I guess, adding public double Weight; field to the SkuInfo isn't hard, but where and how I need to specify it later?
This is how I declare process pipeline:
List<SkuInfo> learn_set = new List<SkuInfo>();
//...filling learn_set with SkuInfo instances
var trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable<SkuInfo>(learn_set);
var dataProcessPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "Label", inputColumnName: sku_info_field_to_predict)
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText(outputColumnName: "TitleFeaturized", inputColumnName: nameof(SkuInfo.sku)))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(outputColumnName: "Features", "TitleFeaturized"))
                .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext);

I think, this is where I need to specify weights property, but I can't find anything similar for that in:
.Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text. and .Append(mlContext.Transforms..
How should I specify the weight property here?
I use SdcaMultiClassTrainer or OVAAveragedPerceptronTrainer trainers.
This is the learning code:
var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline.Append(trainer).Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

var crossValidationResults = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.CrossValidate(data: trainingDataView, estimator: trainingPipeline, numberOfFolds: 6, labelColumnName: "Label");

TransformerChain<Microsoft.ML.Transforms.KeyToValueMappingTransformer> trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);

